# how to find displaying data where data not exist in the other table

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 tables:

table_1:

```
| id | test |total_employee|
+----+------+--------------+
| 1  | xxxx |       3      |
| 2  | yyyy |       2      |
| 3  | zzzz |       3      |
----------------------------
```

table_2:

```
| id | id_table1 |id_employee|
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 1  |    1      |     1     |
| 2  |    1      |     2     |
| 3  |    1      |     3     |
| 4  |    1      |     1     |
| 5  |    1      |     2     |
| 6  |    1      |     1     |
| 7  |    1      |     2     |
| 8  |    1      |     3     |
-----------------------------
```

table employee:

```
    | id | name |
    +----+------+
    | 1  | emp1 |
    | 2  | emp2 |
    | 3  | emp3 |
    -------------
```

and now I want to display all employees from table employee and from table_2 if the employee record in table employee exists but in table_2 it does not. If record  does not exist mark as "unchecked" but if exists mark as "checked".

The point is how to find data from table_employee no matter data is exist or not exist on table_2.

Answer (score 0):

The IF() operation lets you do this:

```
SELECT e.*, IF(ISNULL(t2.id), 'unchecked', 'checked') AS `checked` 
FROM table_employee e 
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.id_employee = e.id
```

Comment: sorry i changed my question , how to find data from table_employee no matter data is exist or not exist on table_2.d